# Does maps of rocky habitats exist?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, europe, data-mapping

I am working on a multifactorial model to explain preferences for a given habitat for a species of bird,
on a European scale. In this model, I have included variables such as slope or terrain ruggedness, which caraterize mountain habitat. However, I would like to be a little more precise regarding presence of rocks, boulders, screes, or anything related to broken rock fragments. My research has been unsuccessful so far, I could only find lithological maps, which is not quite my goal.

Do you know if such maps exist? Or is there a proxy that I have not thought about?

I am new to habitat modelling, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

(I use both QGIS and R)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is any pan European dataset that maps boulders!

In the UK the national mapping agency OS will map on 1:25,000 scree, boulder fields and the like, I suspect this data is in OS MasterMap. I would imagine other national mapping agencies will capture similar detail although quality and resolution will surely vary.

There are very few datasets that map consistently across different nations and at scale that could identify fine detail.

The only cross-continental dataset that I'm aware of is OpenStreetMap and this is unlikely to capture what you are looking for in any consistent manner.